# How to load json data in controller using services in angular?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, json

I am trying to display json data which I am getting from my rails controller in my views. But I believe I am missing something while calling the service in my app controller.

```
**My service**
.service("articles", function($http){

        var o =  this;
        o.getall = function(){
        return  $http.get('/articles.json').then(function(response){
          console.log(response.data);
            return response.data;
          });
        };
       });

   **My controller**
   .controller('FirstCtrl', function($scope, articles, Data){

        var first = this;
        first.message = "Welcome!"
        first.data = articles.getall();
        });

   **Angular route**
   $stateProvider.state("first", {
        url : "",
        controller : "FirstCtrl as first",
        templateUrl: "templates/first.html"
       });

     First.html
   <h1> Angular-rails </h1>
   <h2>{{first.message}}</h2>
    <div ng-repeat="article in first.data">
    <h2>{{article.title}}</h2>
    <h2>{{article.description}}</h2>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

return the promise from service to controller, like this

```
*My service**
.service("articles", function($http){
    var o =  this;
    o.getall = function(){
    return  $http.get('/articles.json');
    };
   });

**My controller**
.controller('FirstCtrl', function($scope, articles, Data){
    var first = this;
    first.message = "Welcome!"
      articles.getall().then(function(response){
      console.log(response.data);
        first.data = response.data;
      });;
    });

**Angular route**
$stateProvider.state("first", {
    url : "",
    controller : "FirstCtrl as first",
    templateUrl: "templates/first.html"
   });

 First.html
<h1> Angular-rails </h1>
<h2>{{first.message}}</h2>
<div ng-repeat="article in first.data">
<h2>{{article.title}}</h2>
<h2>{{article.description}}</h2>
  </div>
```

Comment: This is working fine but could you pls tell what went wrong with my code. And what are the other solutions.  Any tutorial, references?